# How can I create a VMWare virtual machine that boots an existing (EFI) Fedora installation?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a Fedora and Windows installation on the same disk, and have been trying to get VMWare Workstation Player in Windows to boot the Fedora partition, but for some reason the machine doesn't boot.

I have tried creating an IDE disk using the swap and LVM partitions on my physical disk, which goes straight to network boot (yes, the disk has the highest boot priority), and using the swap, LVM and **EFI** partitions which results in an error telling me that the disk is in use:
[image] 
What am I missing here?
**EDIT:** Something I forgot to mention the first time round, the partition numbers shown in the screenshot don't match what Disk Management shows. Anything important?

Comment: Well, the disk *is* in use, right? Windows probably claims the ESP. However, you don’t need it. Just create a new one on a separate virtual hard drive.

Comment: @DanielB But if I understand correctly, GRUB is installed on the ESP. So should I copy the Fedora files over, or do I need it all?

Comment: @DanielB I tried copying the fedora folder over to a new virtual disk's EFI partition, setting it as the primary disk and booting but nothing has changed. It's going straight to network boot